# Microsoft Graph - Email Delivery Failure when using sendMail API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having issue with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<*userId*>/sendMail.

I get 202 Accepted as response, however when I browsed to the user's mailbox above, I'm receiving delivery failure notification as below:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

<username>@outlook.com
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.
```

```
Remote Server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653 AS(7171) [SYBPR01MB4428.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com]'
```

When I logon to Outlook and send email to <*username*>@outlook.com from <*userId*>'s Outlook, the email was sent successfully.

Anyone know what's happening here?

I've tried to add a SMTP connector, but doesn't fixed the problem. When SMTP connector send an email to test Outbound Email, it works fine as I can receive at `<_username_>@outlook.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [link provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online), it explains what is happening

> 5.7.708 Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP
>
> The majority of traffic from this tenant has been detected as suspicious and has resulted in a ban on sending ability for the tenant.
>
> Ensure that any compromises or open relays have been resolved, and then contact support through your regular channel.
>
> For more information, see [Fix email delivery issues for error codes 5.7.700 through 5.7.750 in Exchange Online.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online/fix-error-code-5-7-700-through-5-7-750)

Comment: The email that I am using to send email from is one of the *.onmicrosoft.com account.
weird part is sending email through Outlook works fine, just not when i am using API.

Comment: Microsoft Support has fixed the problem by whitelist the tenant domain name (NOT tenantId.)

Comment: Any new findings here? Got the same behavior when sending mails via graph from one test-tenant-mailbox to another test-tenant-mailbx (same tenant): Server returns 550 5.7.708.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know what's happening here?

Hopefully, I can since I have been through this same issue. In one of the comments you mention that the sending email is of this format - `*.onmicrosoft.com`, which means your app's account is a Trial (unpaid) account.

AFAIK, Microsoft doesn't allow sending emails using Graph API for the trial accounts.

Sending directly from Outlook works since it doesn't involve using Graph API.

So if you're sure that your IP is not blocklisted by Microsoft, then  there are 2 solutions for this issue:

- Use a paid account
- Contact Microsoft support about this issue

In my case, I realized that there is no setting I can do from my end to make this issue go away, so I had to contact Microsoft support.